# Azure Load Balancer Default Message when Server Unavailable

Tags: azure, load, azure-load-balancer

I have an Azure Load Balancer configured over 4 IIS Web Servers. Is there a way to have a static content/page loaded with some info if in case all the Web Servers are unavailable?

P.S. I understand we can use Application Gateway which would allow routing to static pages, but considering the cost of Gateway, it doesn't justify the purpose.

Comment: You can have it in web.config?

Comment: But I am targeting the scenario where the Web Servers are all unavailable.